# Exporting Workflow (and not to Visio)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, export

Have you ever designed a workflow in SharePoint Designer?  If so, then you'll know what they look like in SharePoint Designer.

I am looking for a way to export my worflow.  Not to Visio either.  I know how to export to Visio and Visual Studio.  Those ways do not provide me what I seek (export to visio and check out your workflow in Visio - it's useless because it doesn't keep the data or what lists are which..it just outlines the workflow in very generic terms).

When vieiwing a workflow in SP Designer, you can see, (for example, a Personal Information List I have in SP)

If Current Item:Name no equals Personal Information:Name
Create item in Personal Information
Else
Update item in Personal Email

And so on...and so on....until the end of the my workflow.

I want to export that and get it on paper to document the workflow for a knowledge transfer I'm doing.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Anybody had any luck figuring out a way to export the data yet? So disappointing that it doesn't show what the conditions are or data for set field etc. Should have looked into it more before installing Visio Premium, this doesn't save me that much work in documenting my WF's.

Answer (score 1):

There's no tooling out there that'll do this for you thawt I know of. However, you could try to generate your own by passing the workflow's XOML definition file through an xsl, outputting an indented "tree" of stepd your WF is performing. Export your WF to Visual Studio and open the XOML file as and XML file (instead of double clicking it and showing it in the designer. Nice idea BTW, gonna see if i can build something of my own too :-D. If I do, I'll share it here.

Comment: I wish I could say I understood what you said, but I can't.  Sounds interesting through and would love to know your solution, if you make it reality.  Would be great for knowledge transfers since I design many workflows for clients.